# How many trinary strings are there?

Tags: combinatorics

How many trinary strings (made out of $0,1,2$) of length $30$ are there, such that there are $12$ $2$'s and the difference between the number of $0$'s and $1$'s is not greater than $2$?

My solution:
first we choose the placement for $12$ $2$'s which is $C(30,12)$ ($C$ for "choose") and then there are 3 possibilities:

$10$ times $1$ and $8$ times $0$

$10$ times $0$ and $8$ times $1$

$9$ times $1$ and $9$ times $0$

so the solution is $C(30,12)[C(18,9)+C(18,8)+(18,10)]$

Am I correct?
thanks

Comment: I suppose yes...

Comment: Yes, this looks good.

Comment: Maybe add a line explaining that it is impossible for the number of $0's$ to differ from the number of $1's$ by exactly $1$.